# Get file before and after git diff

Tags: git, git-diff, monaco-editor

I need do develop an UI like this in javascript

[image]

I think I will use [Monaco Diff editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-diffeditor-hello-diff-world). What I'm looking for is a way to get a file before the changes and after the changes. Actually if I exec `git diff my file.ext` the output is not what I'm looking for. What I want is a command to get the file before and an other command to get the file after.

With these commands I'll be able to bind the "beforeFile" to the original model and the "afterFile" to the modifiedModel.

If there is no command to do so, is there a way to transform the output of git diff in two files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get an arbitrary version of any file in the repository using, for example, `git cat-file`, e.g. for commit `foo`:

```
git cat-file blob foo:path/to/file
```

The file path is relative to the root of the repository. The file's contents will go to `stdout`.

Full documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file

PS. also look at `git difftool` which is a way to create the base files for a tool like you envision and then pass them to a program. It may not fit your use case but might provide some inspiration.

Comment: So I have to use foo as current commit for after and parent commit for before ?

Comment: @GitHarpon yes, if you want the before/after for that commit. So, you could use `foo` and `foo~` (though for merge commits that might not make as much sense).

Comment: Then what do you need to do about merge ?

Comment: @GitHarpon you can use the exact same thing for merges and it will work, but merges usually have three versions (previous on one branch, previous on other branch and new). On a merge commit you can access the two previous versions as `foo^1` and `foo^2`.